# Why we need to create a function in model page for relation

Tags: laravel

```
public function single($category, $slug)
{
    $category = Category::where('slug', $category)->first();
    $article = Article::where('slug', $slug)->where('category_id', $category->id)->first();
    $data['comments'] = Comment::where('article_id', $article->id)->get();
}
```

These codes are on my controller page. When I take the comments on my article page it is working fine.
But on the laravel webpage, they say we have to create function in Model.  Why we need to create a function in Model page? My structure is working fine without extra function.
I will be glad if you explain, thank you.

Comment: Could you please try again in explaining what exactly the problem is? Neither your code nor your explanation are clear enough.

Comment: the problem with your code is that you open tow db connections first to get the article and the second to get its comment when using relations in laravel mode and calling "with" function you only open one db connection this is the first part (please refer to laravel eager loading for bigger data fetching https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). the second part is code simplicity as in your code you have tow lines of code but when using model relations it will be Article::with('comments')->get(); this is much readable and easier. Hope this is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

the difference is you can do something like this with a single db query and alter the results:

```
public function single($category, $slug)
{
$category->where('slug', $category)->articles()->where('slug', $slug)->with('comments');
}
```